# Terminal-mode not working with Ctrl-W

Tags: key-bindings, terminal

I am trying to work more with the built-in terminal for vim 8.1 and reading through the docs noticed it has two keybindings for entering the normal `Terminal-mode`. `CTRL+\ CTRL+N` as well as `CTRL+W CTRL+N`.

While The `CTRL+\ CTRL+N` works the other does not, it seems that `CTRL+W CTRL+N` is associated with the `:new` command as well.  Is this expected behavior or is there possibly a setting that I have on that might effect this that I can't find?

Comment: According to help the two equivalent commands are `Ctrl-W N` and `Ctrl-\ Ctrl-N`, i.e. the first one uses unadorned `N`. It's separate from the "create a new  window" command.

Comment: Make sure to use a **capital** N, not a lowercase n

Comment: Thanks, that actually was the issue... the capital.. I can't believe I made such a simple mistake.

Comment: Thanks, `Ctrl-\ Ctrl-n` switched me back to `NORMAL` mode, so I was able to move across windows with `Ctrl-w` again.  A bit tricky, a question of habit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after the obvious blunder of not using a **capital N** ‍♂️ ... I was able to get the remap working with the lowercase n (just for terminal) which is what I was hoping to get.  This was done by adding the following to my vim startup.

```
tnoremap <C-W>n <C-\><C-n>
```

Comment: Just want to chime in that I too made the blunder of not realizing they meant capital N. Also typing C-\ is impossible on a nordic keyboard layout as `\` is not accessible without holding other modifier keys (Swedish Mac layout requires Alt-Shift-7).